# Wordpress Dropdowns

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of creating a Wordpress theme for a non-profit and I'd like to be able to create dropdown menus for them. However for some reason, the dropdowns do not line up with the parent page item, i.e. I set the item 'Resources' as having 'About' about for a parent page and when you hover over About, the Resources tab is not lined up under About. Hope this makes sense.

Here is the code.

The HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/raf/" title="Home">Home</a></li>

<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=8">News</a>

<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item page-item-75"><a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=75">And Yet Another</a></li></ul></li>

<li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=12">About</a>
<ul class='children'><li class="page_item page-item-70"><a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=70">Dropdown Menu</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-73"><a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=73">Another Dropdown</a></li></ul></li>

</ul></div>
</div><!--End #nav-->
```

And the CSS...

```
#nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 38px;
left: 0;
height:20px;
float: left;
width: 190px;
z-index: 99999;         
}

#nav ul ul a {
color:#555;
font-size:12px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#nav ul ul li {
top:0;
min-width: 180px;
background-color:#333;
}

#nav ul ul ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0; 
}

#nav ul ul a {
font-size:12px;
background: #e5e5e5;
line-height: 1em;
padding: 15px;
width: 160px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Thanks a heap! Hope someone can help with this.

jrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem was that I needed to add position:relative to the parent elements, i.e. the list items in the parent ul. Thanks to everyone who took time to try and help me out!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a CSS correction you need to make. Familiarize yourself with Firebug or Chrome web inspector if you are doing to be working on front-end of websites.
If you had a link to the website, I would be able to tell you what to fix.
Also, you should really not be using absolute paths in your code. It will make your transfer process a lot easier.

Replace: `<a href="http://localhost/raf/?page_id=8">News</a>`

With: `<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?page_id=8">News</a>`

If you can use Wordpress dynamic menus, even better (http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

Comment: Thanks, I really don't have absolute paths in my code, that is just what I cut and pasted from the source code in my browser window. It is all created dynamically with the Wordpress menus. Also, I have been trying to edit the CSS through Firebug, a tool which I use frequently, but I don't know what the CSS correction need to be. Any thoughts on the CSS to fix the problem?

Comment: If you send me a link to the page, I should be able to use firebug and let you know

Comment: I got it to work for me, but the dropdowns don't line up with the parent elements. Can someone take a look for me?

http://rescuedadoptionfund.org/dev

Comment: In your style.css on line 374, change margins to: 33px auto 0 -88px;